# ColdFusion 9 CFScript Query with multiple id's

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

How using CFScript can you do a get in value list. below works if I pass in one id but what do you do to pass in multiple id's?

```
// Get Modules By IDs
function getModulesByIDs(string dsn,required numeric pIDS) {
     // Setup a variable for the Query Result
    var qResult = '';
    // Setup the Query variable
    var q= new query();
    // Add Parameter 
    q.addParam(name="ID", value=arguments.pIDS, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER");
    // Create the SQL String
    var sqlString="
            SELECT    ROLEID,
                      ROLENAME,
                      NAME,
                      MODULENAME
            FROM      MODULEROLE
            WHERE     
                      MODULEIDS IN :ID
        ";
    q.setdatasource(arguments.pDsn);
    q.setsql(sqlString);
    qResult=q.execute().getresult();
    return qResult;  
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `list` attribute to indicate the `value` contains multiple id's and add parenthesis to construct a proper IN (..) clause.

```
q.addParam(name="ID", value=arguments.pIDS, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER", list="true");
...
var sqlString="... WHERE MODULEIDS IN (:ID )";
```

Comment: Is there something like this for using a Param for a sort statement?

Comment: No. Bind parameters prevent values from being evaluated as sql. So they cannot be used in place of object names, like a columnName in an `ORDER BY` clause.